# Google Sites. JS connection with spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-sites

Using Google Sites, How can I connect to another user spreadsheet using username and password, alike one usually does with mysql?

I tried the following, but it did not work :

```
var opts = {dataType:'json',username:'xxxxx',password:'xxxxxx'};
var query = new google.visualization.Query(urlTable, opts);
```

Comment: How did'nt it work ? Error message ?

Answer (score 0):

yes i need to connect to a spreadsheet, who owner is other user(spreadsheet is in other account), from code JS with top two lines that i posted at the first post in this thread

using username and password that i have

i see this https://developers.google.com/gadgets/docs/oauth#examples but i dont understand well

thanks

Answer (score -3):

The error in site is Access denied because the owner of document is other gmail account...

Comment: I think the question was how to do it when you have the other userid/password.